# Are there any polygon triangulation tools for Android OpenGL ES?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to build my new android game. I went through the tutorials of opengl es 1.1 and many web sites about opengl es 1.1. I got to know that the rendering in opengl es is only by point, line and triangles.

Concept wise this looks right. But I was wondering if i have to build a character for my game I need to do a lot of work in converting or splitting up the character into lot of triangles. I was wondering if there is a tool something like a google sketchup that will help me build 3d objects and give me the list of triangles that will help me reproduce the same image in android with opengl es? is there a way out for this. 
  Please help me with any kind of information that you feel will be helpful for me in this regards of breaking a 3D model into a list of triangles with proper vertices. 
Thank you very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most 3D modelling tools store their meshes into a list of triangles, but usually into their own custom format. Fortunately there are a few formats that are very easy to write a parser to import into OpenGL|ES.

Since most tools require a paid version, I would advise to go with a free one, like [blender](http://www.blender.org/) and export the model of choice using [**wavefront**](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/txt/obj_format.txt) format, that gives you a list of vertices, normals, texture coordinates, etc in plain text or **raw** which just dumps all the vertices into a file.

Either way will require a bit of code to load the file and put into the right format to render it, but there are plenty of resources on the web of how to do it.